# Database table design for a multi-language dictionary application, any recommendation?

Tags: database-design

I want to build a dictionary iphone app for my language associated with many different languages. Thus, one word in the original language will have different translations into different languages. Do you have any recommendation for such a database design using SQL? 
Thanks a bunch guys/gals.

```
#Database: MySQL
#Language: Python
#Platform: Google App Engine
#Application: multi-language Dictionary
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like one-to-many between the table with the base language Word and another Translation table that would have the language, translated value, and foreign key to the base Word.